# C: Is it possible to automatically create a given number of arrays?

Tags: c, arrays

Is it possible in anyway to recursively create a given number of arrays in C with predetermined length? I want to experiment with arrays for a clustering project and would be really practical if i could do this.

Comment: Yes it is. Let's try that and ask us if you're stuck somewhere.

Comment: not sure you need recursion. a simple for loop will suffice.

Comment: @ouah This approach is appropriate. It is an iterative approach as opposed to a recursive approach, but I fail to see how a recursive approach would be better in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible, allocate an array of pointers then allocate all the arrays:

```
T **array = malloc(rows * sizeof *array);

for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    array[i] = malloc(cols * sizeof **array);
}
```

it create `rows` numbers of array. Each array is an array of `cols` numbers of `T`.

Comment: and don't forget to clean up your memory

Comment: the type `T` is c++ specific, is it not?

Comment: An alternative is allocating one huge piece of memory and then parceling it out to the sub-allocations. Just beware of Alignment requirements. See `_Alignof`,

Comment: @ryyker `T` is here an alias for the desired type

Comment: @ryyker: it is just a place holder.

Comment: Wow, spontaneous support. Thanx to all. @ouah for some reason it is giving me an error on that T.

Comment: @dimits.mark  read the previous comments, i.e. `T` is a mnemonic for type.  Replace the "T" with a regular C type such as char, int, float, etc.

Comment: Wow this is a really nice approach. I needed some more info to understand this. Thanks :)

Comment: Would this suffice? `for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)`
  `free(array[i]);`
 `free(array);`